# Preventing Enter key from triggering OK in QButtonBox in particular QLineEdit QButtonBox

Tags: qt

I have a Dialog which has some widgets such as `QComboBox`, `QSpinBox` and some `QLineEdit`. At the bottom of the widget, I have a `QButtonBox`. Clicking enter in any one of the widgets will trigger the `accepted()` slot for the `QButtonBox`. However, I'd like to disable this automated action in one of the `QLineEdits`. So, pressing `Enter` key in one of the `QLineEdit` wouldn't trigger the `accepted()` slot for the `QButtonBox`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to install an [EventFilter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/eventsandfilters.html). Something like:

```
 bool FilterObject::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
 {
     if (object == target && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
         QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
         if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Enter) {
             // Special key handling
             return true;
         } else
             return false;
     }
     return false;
 }
```